# Create a Python script which compares several excel files(snapshots) and compares and creates a new dataframe with rows which are different

Tags: pandas, dataframe, validation, compare, difference

I am new in Python and will appreciate your help.

I would like to create a python script which performs data validation by using my first file excel_file[0] as df1 and comparing it against several other excel_file[0:100] and looping through them while comparing with df1 and appending those rows which are different to a new dataframe df3. Even though I have several columns, I would like to base my comparison on two columns which includes a primary key column; such that if the keys in the two dataframes match; then compare df1 and df2(loop).

Here's what I have tried..

```
## import python module: pandasql which allows SQL syntax for Pandas; 
It needs installation first though:pip install -U pandasql
    from pandasql import sqldf
    pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, locals(), globals() )
    dateTimeObj = dt.datetime.now()
    print('start file merge: ' ,dateTimeObj)
#path = os.getcwd()
##files = os.listdir(path1)
files=os.path.abspath(mydrive')
files
dff1 = pd.DataFrame()
##df2 = pd.DataFrame()
# method 1
excel_files = glob.glob(files+ "\*.xlsx")
##excel_files = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == '\*.xlsx' or f[-3:] == '*.xls']
df1=pd.read_excel(excel_files[14])
for f in excel_files[0:100]:
    
    df2 = pd.read_excel(f)
    ## Lets drop the any unnamed column
    ##df1=df1.drop(df1.iloc[:, [0]], axis = 1)
    ### Gets all Rows and columns which are different after comparing the two dataframes ; The 
    clause " _key HAVING COUNT(*)= 1" resolves to True if the two dataframes are different
    ### Else we use The clause " _key HAVING COUNT(*)= 2" to output similar rows and columns
    data=pysqldf("SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM df1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM df2) df1 GROUP BY _key 
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 ;")
    
   ## df = dff1.append(data).reset_index(drop = True)
print(dt.datetime.now().strftime("%x %X")+': files appended to make a Master file')
```